# I want to reverse the order of the 2 activities

Tags: android

I am working on a project, where I have 2 activities :RegisterActivity and MainActivity .This is my initial code and  I want to reverse the order of the two activities so that first lauched activity will be MainActivity then RegisterActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.training.h2">
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have tried some tutorials from net  but is crashing.

thanks for any help

Comment: What do you mean you are trying to reverse the order? You are trying to reverse the order in which the activities are displayed to your user?

Comment: @Stephen - exactly ,  I want to reverse the order of the two activities so that first lauched activity will be MainActivity then RegisterActivity. Thanks

Comment: Move the <intent-filter> element from RegisterActivity and add it to MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android manifest file does not specify which order activities are displayed per se. You can specify *some* relations like parent child hierarchy, or set which activities are launcher activities (the activity that is opened when you click on the app icon).

The intent filter here will specify which activity is the launcher activity:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

So in order to make your MainActivity show first, you would need to move the intent filter into that Activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".RegisterActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Once your app is launched though, it is up to the logic of your application to determine what activity will come next after the launcher activity.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Intent-Filter accordingly in Manifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```